# Existence of a special section (fiber bundle)

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

I'm learning about fiber bundles and I have the following question.

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle (let's assume it is trivial) and let $U$ be an open connected set of $E$. Let $V=p(U)$. Is it always true that there exists a section $s$ such that $s(V)\subseteq U$?

Thank you (any reference about this kind of problems is welcome).

Comment: So $E = B \times F$. Any assumptions on the fiber $F$?

Comment: No further assumption!